# how to loop through sub folders and rename to parent - folder - file number

Tags: batch-rename

Here are my folders:

```
Dexter\Season 1\season 1 ep 1  
Dexter\Season 1\season 1 ep 1  
Dexter\Season 2\season 1 ep 1  
Dexter\Season 2\season 1 ep 1  
Dexter\Season 3\season 1 ep 1  
Dexter\Season 3\season 1 ep 1
```

I am currently in `Dexter\`

What I want to do is loop through all the sub folders in Dexter and rename all the files accordingly:

```
Dexter\Season 1\season 1 ep 1 -> Dexter\Season 1\1x1
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Windows? Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I'm wasting my summer inside anyways I might aswell do something helpful, and write the script for you. Assuming you're using Windows, the following PowerShell script would fit your scenario (just save as a .ps1 file and modify the path at the top).

```
$TVShowFolderPath = "X:\Series\Dexter";

$TVShowSeasons=$(get-childitem "$TVShowFolderPath");

foreach( $s in $TVShowSeasons)
{
    if( ($s.PSisContainer) -and ($s -imatch "^(Season )(\d{2}|\d{1})$") )
    {
        $season = $matches[2];
        write-host "Season $season";

        $episodes=$(get-childitem $s.FullName);

        foreach( $ep in $episodes)
        {
            if( $ep -imatch "^(season) (\d{2}|\d{1}) (ep) (\d{2}|\d{1})(.*)$")
            {
                $newName = "$($season)x$($matches[4])$($matches[5])";
                write-host "`tEpisode: `"$($ep.Name)`" --> `"$newName`"";
                Rename-Item $ep.FullName $newName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to see if it spits out the correct names first just comment out the line starting with "Rename-Item".

Comment: Thanks for that. 
I was after more of a batch rather than PowerShell. I have a batch script which I am wanting to add this to.

Comment: To launch the PowerShell script from a batch script;
powershell "& '%~dp0\renameScript.ps1'" 
PS: Enable execution of PowerShell scripts, start PS as admin and type "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned" (This can also be added to the batch script.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I have been trying to enable execution of powershell. I don't know how to start PS?